# How can I turn a list of comma separated values into an array?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, keyboard-shortcuts

If I have a formula:

```
={1,2,3,4,5}
```

I get a 5 column set of numbers with 1 in the first, 2 in the next and so on.

However, if I have a cell that contains the string `1,2,3,4,5` in cell E2
and I try

```
={E2}
```

I get the same result as if I did `=E2` - a single cell with comma separated values.

Is there a function in Google Sheets that says, "treat the argument as if it were typed at this point?

Comment: The `INDIRECT` function is capable of doing that, but in this instance, the formula throws an error as the INDIRECT formula needs a cell/range reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- instead **`={E2}`** use **`SPLIT`** formula like:

  ```
  =SPLIT(E2; ",")
  ```

  [image]
- also, you can do it directly by pressing <kbd>**`LEFT ALT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`D`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`E`**</kbd>